# comparar Array com outro Array com for no Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, loop, arraylist

Galera, Boa tarde.

estou querendo comparar 2 Array, onde 1 array possui valor setado aleatoriamente.
Estou querendo usar for para não ter que repetir 100 vezes. Porém não estou sabendo, pois sempre me mostra só o ultimo valor do Array;
Vamos lá, quero isso.

```
 btQuestions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random randomico = new Random();
            int perguntaaleatoria = randomico.nextInt(perguntas.length);


                 textQuestions.setText(perguntas[perguntaaleatoria]);


for(int i = 0;i < perguntas.length; i++) {
                     for (int j = i; j < respostas.length; j++) {


                         if (perguntas[i].equals(textQuestions.getText())) {
                             textoResposta.setText(respostas[j]);
                         }
                     }

                 }
```

no momento esta assim:

```
if (perguntas[1].equals(textQuestions.getText())) {
                  textoResposta.setText(respostas[1]);
              }
              if (perguntas[2].equals(textQuestions.getText())) {
                  textoResposta.setText(respostas[2]);
              }
              if (perguntas[3].equals(textQuestions.getText())) {
                  textoResposta.setText(respostas[3]);
```

Na segunda não apresenta erro, mais imagina isso com 100 questões! OO"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para iterar todas, você deve remover o laço de interno (`j`), e assim, fazer sua “comparação em arrays“, conforme pergunta:

```
for(int i = 0;i < perguntas.length; i++) {
    if (perguntas[i].equals(textQuestions.getText())) {
        textoResposta.setText(respostas[i]);
     }
}
```

Mas você não precisa disso, já que tem o índice da questão armazenado em `int perguntaaleatoria`. Portanto pode fazer apenas assim:

```
int perguntaaleatoria = randomico.nextInt(perguntas.length);
textQuestions.setText(perguntas[perguntaaleatoria]);
textoResposta.setText(respostas[perguntaaleatoria]);
```

Comment: sbrubes, Bom dia mano! Trabalha com isso? Queria ter esse raciocínio, eu achando que tinha que ter o for, ainda fiquei uns 5 minutos pra entender o que você fez, que pelo que entendi não esta comparando a pergunta e a resposta, mas sim pegando o mesmo int aleatório pras 2, assim setando ambos com o mesmo valor. Bateu até um desanimo. kkk Brigadão mano!! Valeu mesmo.

Comment: Esquenta não brow, são mais de 15 anos fazendo isso.. Leva tempo mesmo.. 
Continue firme, estudando e se aprimorando! Qualquer coisa estamos aí, abraço!

Comment: Ai sbrubes, tentei implementar para usar perguntaaleatória em qualquer classe, Mas ai a desconfigurou a comparação, fiz assim. public void onClick(View v) { textQuestions.setText(perguntas[numberAleatory()]); textoResposta.setText(respostas[numberAleatory()]); public int numberAleatory(){ Random randomico = new Random(); int perguntaaleatoria = randomico.nextInt(perguntas.length); return(perguntaaleatoria); Que fiz errado?

Comment: Cara.. cada vez que você chamar esse função `numberAleatory` vai gerar um novo número randômico, e aí não vai funcionar mesmo. Você deve armazenar isso em uma variável, mas qualquer coisa posta uma nova pergunta pra ficar mais claro para todos. ;)

Comment: Brigadão mano, eu recuperei o valor e ai deu certo, já tinha até feito antes. Brigadão mesmo. Pode fechar o tópico como respondido, não sei como faz. Rsrs.